# how can i pass queryparams to my resolver

Tags: html, angular, angular-resolver

here is my ngOnInit in my component -

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
      (params) => {
        console.log(params);
      }
    )
  }
```

here is my resolver -

```
class ProductsResolver implements Resolve<
      Pick<IProductInterface, 'image' | 'title' | 'price' | 'description'>[]>
{
  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Pick<
  IProductInterface, 'image' | 'title' | 'price' | 'description'>[]
  > {
    return this.productService.getProducts(
      route.paramMap.get('gender')! as ProductGender,
      +route.paramMap.get('category')! as ProductCategory,
      );
  }
}
```

how can i pass the params to the resolver.
i am trying to get from my nav a link and then go to product-list page and present the data with the queryParams.

my html -

```
<a
   class="linkCategoriesInner__link"
   [routerLink]="['/product-list']"
   [queryParams]="{ gender: 'women', category: 6 }">
   Hats
</a>
```

Comment: What's the problem? ParamMap doesn't exist in the resolver? Why do you even want to use a resolver? You could just call the service in the component where you subscribe to `queryParams`

Comment: yes the ParamMap dont get to the resolver @funkizer

Answer (score 0):

I think Resolvers are a thing from the past (AngularJS versions below 2). This is how I would do it: Assign an Observable from the service to the template and subscribe to it using `AsyncPipe`. This way it's safe for `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

```
// component.ts

constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.products$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap(pMap => this.productService.getProducts(
        pMap.get('gender') as ProductGender,
        +pMap.get('category') as ProductCategory
      )
    )
  )
}
```

```
<!-- component.html -->
<ng-container *ngIf="products$ | async as products">
    {{ products | json }}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: would you mind to talk in discord maybe? i see you got a lot of years using angular and i got some question.
Daniel#6172

Answer (score 0):

Resolvers get all the parameters of the route, you may access them using the `route.paramMap` member as usual.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4hcqvx?file=src/app/my-resolver.service.ts)